# Adding new lines when returning JSX object

Tags: reactjs, newline, render, jsx

Hello I have some data that I'm trying to render out.  I would like to be able to have newlines that render out properly when returning my component using React.  Right now it just renders the 
, /n, or whatever as a string.  Is it possible to contain a newline character in my data so when I render the data out new lines occur?

Data below...

```
const imgPath = '/public/../../../img/';

const TempHelpData = [
    {
        name: 'testing',
        image: `${imgPath}boardAndCant.PNG`,
        subject: "1. yadda \<br \/> <br /> \n yadda",
        troubleshoot: "suggestions",
        video: "no video has been made for this subject"    
    },

    {
        name: 'one',
        image: `${imgPath}boardAndCant.PNG`,
        subject: "1. yadda yadda",
        troubleshoot: "suggestions",
        video: "no video has been made for this subject"
    },
]

export default TempHelpData;
```

Render Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import TempHelpData from '../data/TempHelpData'
import sass from '../scss/application.scss'


class HelpFileContainerRender extends Component {

    render() {
        const renderHelpFile = this.props.data.filter(obj => {

            return this.props.name === obj.name;
                }).map((obj, idx) => {
                return (
                    <div key={idx}>
                        <div className="divImg">
                            <img src={`${obj.image}`} className="helpFileImg"></img>< br/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                <span>Name:</span> {obj.name} < br/>
                                <span>Subject:</span> {obj.subject} <br />
                                <span>Troubleshooting:</span> {obj.troubleshoot} <br />
                                <span>Video:</span> {obj.video} <br />
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                {renderHelpFile}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class HelpFileContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <HelpFileContainerRender data={this.props.data} name={this.props.name} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

HelpFileContainer.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.object
    ),
    name: PropTypes.string
}

HelpFileContainer.defaultProps = {
    data: TempHelpData,
    name: ''
}

export default HelpFileContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using \n, you could use `<br />` in the data and then put it in the jsx with [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html)

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'hello <br /> goodbye' }} />`

Comment: What is content referencing?  Do I place dangerouslySetInnerHTML to HelpFileContainer, HelpFileContainerDiv, or the span?

Comment: It would be something like `{__html: 'hello <br  /> goodbye' }`

Comment: Not sure how that is helpful. I'm trying to render out the data objects and can't place a static __html unless it goes inside the span???